# ZFS Shares not exported until sharenfs property re-set on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, zfs, zfsonlinux

I am setting up ZFS and NFS on Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS and have a weird issue that is causing me to go crazy. I have set up ZFS and NFS using ZFS shares as described in https://pthree.org/2012/12/31/zfs-administration-part-xv-iscsi-nfs-and-samba/. As you can see in my log below, although I have set zfs-share to run `zfs share -a` during boot, the shares are still not exported. Even weirder, is that  `zfs share -a` still doesn't when I manually run it. I can only get zfs shares to work if I reset the `sharenfs` property of one of the shares and then re-run `zfs share -a`. See below

```
$ showmount -e
Export list for apu:
/mnt localhost
$ sudo zfs share -a
$ showmount -e
Export list for apu:
/mnt localhost
$ sudo zfs share pool1
cannot share 'pool1': filesystem already shared
$ sudo zfs get sharenfs pool1
NAME   PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
pool1  sharenfs  on        local
$ sudo zfs set sharenfs=on pool1
$ showmount -e
Export list for apu:
/s/apu/a/homes *
/s/apu/a       *
/s/apu/a/sys   *
/mnt           localhost
$ sudo zfs share -a
$ showmount -e
Export list for apu:
/s/apu/b       *
/s/apu/a/homes *
/s/apu/a       *
/s/apu/a/sys   *
/s/apu/b/cwc   *
/mnt           localhost
```

Comment: I don't have an answer but want to direct others with this question to places that may be useful. This question was asked and [answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42533017/9598638). This behavior appears to be a bug in ZFS on Linux and has a currently open [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/7692) (apparently submitted by the author--thank you). If you have this issue as well, commenting on the GitHub issue with additional information about your OS, ZFS, and NFS configurations may be the best way to help the ZFS On Linux developers investigate this.

Answer (score 3):

My Ubuntu 16.04.05 LTS has a similar problem.

First question: are you using **systemd** or the older-style **init** system?   16.04 uses **systemd** by default and the ZFS components are not really well debugged.

Next time you reboot and your shares are not there, try:

```
# systemctl restart zfs-share.service
```

and then see if the shares are there with **showmount**.   BTW on my system I have a problem with the RPC registration service coming up so you might have to do:

```
# systemctl start rpcbind.service
```

if **rpcbind** isn't running first.

If this mitigates your problem you might consider adding those commands to your system rc file but I just do it manually each time I reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem under Ubuntu 16.04, but that probably applies to newer versions as well.
There is a bug that systemd unit `zfs-share.service` does not perform `sharenfs -a` on startup  https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/1375

As a workaround, you can add that to `/etc/rc.local`

```
sudo zfs unshare -a
sudo zfs share -a
```

See this discussion for details: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2107#issuecomment-47182970